# Jenkins problems - how to access global variables in MSBuild file and how to send mail when a condition gets passed

Tags: msbuild, jenkins, email-validation, email-attachments

1. For some reason I have to access Jenkins global environment variables like BUILD ID, etc. in my MSBuild file but I don't know how to do that.
2. After running my NUnit project I create a specific report, a pdf file, but there may be times when this file does not get generated(like when there is no data to show) so I have to check whether this report exists or not and if yes, then I have to attach it in a mail and send to some guys. I am using Email-ext plugin of Jenkins but I am not sure how to check for this condition.

What do you suggest I do for these problems?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't know how Jenkins works, but there should be some way to pass additional command line parameters. To pass Jenkins global variable add /p: switch into the MSBuild command line. Let's say JenkinsVersion is global variable in Jenkins. You can pass it into the MSBuild with `/p:MsBuildJenkinsVariable=JenkinsVersion` . MsBuild $(MsBuildJenkinsVariable) property now should be filled with JenkinsVersion.
2. I know you want to set condition in Jenkins somehow. If it  is not possible to do it in Jenkins, you can do it using MSbuild script. I'm using [MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Communication.Email](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/2439bba8-d062-a4b9-3ca6-2e348d031ec1.htm) MSBuild task to send notification e-mails. Set Condition property of the Email task to send e-mail when report file doesn't exist.

Comment: I am trying to use the email task but I am unable to send mail. I using the following configuration  <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Communication.Email TaskAction="Send" Subject="Test Email" SmtpServer="smtp.gmail.com" MailFrom="vaibhavpanghal@gmail.com" MailTo="vaibhavpanghal@gmail.com" Body="body text" UseDefaultCredentials="false" UserName="vaibhavpanghal@gmail.com" UserPassword="mypassword"  EnableSsl="true" Format="HTML" />

Comment: Run your MSBuild with diagnostic verbosity /v:diag. Try to temporary disable your firewall, antivirus, etc. Or ask directly here http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: It gives the following results - SmtpException : Failure sending result. WebException : Unable to connect to the remote server. SocketException : An attemp was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 173.194.77.109 : 25...really frustrated with this one actually.

Comment: With port 465 it gives smtp time out error but with port 587 it gives the same error as above.

Comment: Did you try to disable your firewall?

Comment: I see that the MSBuildBinPath used is C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\v2.0 and v4.0. Why is that? Can I change it?